# Move index.html from public to src folder without complication error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I want to move my `index.html` file inside `src/` folder from `public/` folder without any compiler errors. How can I do that?

I tried directly moving and compiling with `npm start`. It gave me multiple compiler errors something like modules not found.

Comment: 1. Why? 2. With what other setup (CRA? Vite? Direct Webpack cofiguration?) 3. _What_ errors, exactly?